# Как найти общюю площадь n окружностей (Python3.1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, геометрия, тригонометрия

Помогите найти решения задачи.
Даны точки что являются центрами окружностей и даны радиусы данных окружностей. Нужно найти сумму площадей этих окружностей с вычетом повторяющейся площади. То есть найти площадь красной зоны на картинке (Картинка это лишь визуализация задачи)

[image: Пример]

Comment: Ну вообще это сложная задача. Ограничения какие, дополнительные условия, размер картинки?

Comment: Картинка является лишь визуализацией поставленной задачи. Есть только центральные точки, и радиусы. Нужно найти общую площадь

Comment: Центральные точки в каких координатах?

Comment: Повторяющиеся области нужно вообще не учитывать? Или учитывать один раз? Добавьте больше деталей.

Comment: На картинке красная рамка тех площадей сумму которых нужно найти. Имеется массив с объектами класса Circle у которого есть аргументы x,y, radius.

Comment: Алгоритм Бентли-Оттмана для пересечения отрезков дорабатывается до алгоритма пересекающего окружности. Результат работы - планарный граф с дугами окружностей в качестве рёбер. Для любой грани графа можно вычислить её площадь. Общая сложность - *NlogN + K*, где *K* количество точек пересечений окружностей.

Comment: Если скорость не так важна, можно вышеозначенный граф построить за *N^2*.

Comment: Без построения графа за *N^3* заметанием можно вычислить площадь.

Comment: максимальное количество кругов не дано, так что как понимаю, их может быть довольно много.

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy. Можете рассказать подробнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Модификация метода полос для дуг окружностей

Для всех пар окружностей, если окружности пересекаются, запомним *y*-координаты точек пересечения.

Для всех окружностей отыщем их верхнюю и нижнюю точки и добавим их *y*-координаты в предыдущий массив.

Из массива окружностей составим массив левых и правых полуокружностей (дуг).

Общий массив *y*-координат отсортируем. Выберем из массива соседние элементы *y<sub>i</sub>*, *y<sub>i+1</sub>* и рассмотрим горизонтальную полосу ограниченную этими значениями.

Дуга или пересекает полосу целиком или не пересекается с ней вовсе. Оставим только дуги, пересекающие полосу. Каждая такая дуга пересекается с прямой *y = (y<sub>i</sub> + y<sub>i+1</sub>) / 2* в одной точке и все эти точки различны. Отсортируем дуги по *x*-координатам точек пересечения.

Положим счётчик равным нулю. Перебирём дуги. Для левых дуг увеличиваем счётчик на единицу, для правых уменьшаем. Из всех дуг оставим только левые, перед которыми счётчик был нулевым и правые, после которых счётчик стал нулевым. Остальные дуги убираем.

Выберем вертикальную прямую слева от самой первой дуги. Нас интересует площадь между этой прямой и дугой по горизонтали и внутри слоя по вертикали. Эта площадь вычисляется аналитически.

Переберём дуги и сложим площади. Площади для левых дуг войдут в сумму со знаком минус, площади для правых дуг со знаком плюс. Полученная сумма будет равна площади объединения всех кругов в пересечении с полосой.

Сложим такие площади для всех полос чтобы получить общую площадь пресечения.

Сложность алгоритма в худшем случае *N<sup>3</sup>logN*. В худшем случае получится *N<sup>2</sup>* полос. Обработка одной полосы требует *NlogN* операций (сортировка).

Думаю что до тысячи попарно пересекающихся окружностей обработать можно. Если окружности (почти) не пересекаются, то сложность упадет до *N<sup>2</sup>logN*.

Оптимальный алгоритм ещё примерно на порядок *N* быстрее. Но там сложно, а этот можно собрать из относительно простых шагов.